# What are Pascal Strings?

Tags: string, data-structures, pascal

Are they named after the programming language, or the mathematician?

What are the defining characteristics of Pascal strings? In [Wikipedia's article on strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Length-prefixed) it seems like the defining characteristic is storing the length of the string in the first byte. In another article I get the impression that [the memory layout of the strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930664/how-are-pascal-strings-represented-in-memory) is also important.

While perusing an unrelated SO thread somebody mentioned that [Pascal strings make Excel fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array#comment3358256_492428). What are the advantages of Pascal strings over null-terminated strings? Or more generally, in what situations do Pascal strings excel?

Are Pascal strings implemented in any other languages?

Last, do I capitalize both words ("Pascal Strings") or only the first ("Pascal strings")? I'm a technical writer...

Comment: There is an extensive overview of character and string types in the Lazarus and Free Pascal wiki at http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Character_and_string_types .

Comment: Regarding capitalization, it is "Pascal strings"; there is no reason to write "Strings" with a capital "S".

Comment: But it is Not called Pascal Casing for Nothing.

Comment: A Pascal String is a length prefixed string. It's useful as getting the length of the string or getting the last character of a string can be done in constant time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Pascal strings were made popular by one specific, but huge influential Pascal implementation, named UCSD. So **UCSD Strings** is a better term. This is the same implementation that made bytecode interpreters popular.

In general it is not one specific type, but the basic principle of having the size prefixed to the character data. This makes getting the length a constant time operation (O(1)) instead of scanning the character data for a nul character.

Not all Pascals used this concept. IIRC, the original (seventies) convention was to space pad an allocation, and scan backwards for a non space character (making it impossible for strings to have a terminating space). Moreover, since software was mostly used in isolation, all kinds of schemes were used, often based on what was advantageous for that implementation/architecture.

While the construct is not part of Standard Pascal, the most popular dialects from Borland (Turbo Pascal, Delphi and Free Pascal) generally base themselves on UCSD dialect, and thus have pascal strings, Delphi currently has 5 such strings. (short/ansi/wide/unicode/open)

On the other hand, this means that in a loop, you need some additional check based on indexes to check for the end of the string.

So instead by copying a string using

```
while (p^) do begin P^=p2^; inc(p) inc(p2); end;
```

which is wholly equivalent to

```
while (*s++ = *t++);
```

in C when using an optimizing compiler.

you need to do e.g.

```
while (len>0) do begin p^:=p2^; inc(p) inc(p2); dec(len); end;
```

or even

```
i:=1;
while (i<=len) do begin p[i]:=p2[i]; inc(i); end;
```

This made the number of instructions in a Pascal string loop slightly larger than the equivalent zero terminated string, and adds one more live value. Additionally, UCSD was a bytecode (p-code) interpreter language, and the latter code based on pascal string use is "safe".

In case of an architecture that had built in post increment (++) operators (like the PDP-8,11's C was developed for originally), the pointer version was even cheaper, specially without optimization. Nowadays optimizing compilers could easily detect any of these constructs and convert them to whatever is best.

More importantly, since the early nineties security became more important, and in general solely relying on null terminated strings property is frowned upon because small errors in validation can cause potentially exploitable buffer overflow issues. C and the its standards therefore deprecated the old string use, and now use "-n-" versions of the older string routines (strNcpy etc) that need a maximal length to be passed. This is adds the same extra live value, similar to the length, like a manually managed Pascal strings principle, where the programmer must take care of passing the length (or maximum buffer size for C's -N- functions) around. Pascal strings still have the advantage of getting to the last occupied char in an O(1) operation, and the fact that there are no forbidden chars though.

Length prefixed strings are also used extensively in file format, because, obviously, it is useful to know the number of bytes to read up front.

Comment: or in pascal to most one short string to another:

Move(t[0],s[0],Ord(s[0])); it is as fast as your C example.

Of course, your examples are based upon what is not called "ShortString", and Delphi and new Pascal dialects default to what is called a HugeString or NativeString. Which has a 4 byte length, prior to the data of the string -- in this case referencing [0] is an error. In my compiler, there is more prior to the [1]'s byte - as a String is an object.

Comment: UCSD pascal had no move(), that is a turbo invention,  and doesn't work very well in a bytecode interpreter. Please read the post for historical context.

Comment: The 8086 was designed to support both 'Pascal' strings and 'C' strings: CISC instructions exist for both. The examples here assume that the string pointers and string index are different things. In 8086 code as generated by actual compilers, that was generally not true: the copy loop used only the index or null, the code to update the index was the same length as the code to check for null, but updating the pointer "inc(p)"   was extra, and made the C loop longer than the Pascal loop.

Comment: david: All x86's had rep; movsb for fixed string copying.

Answer (score 15):

It's an old name dating back to the days where "C language versus Pascal language" was actually a comparison people made. Depending on who you ask, it's either specifically storing the length in the first *byte*, or refers to any length prefix (two bytes, four bytes). Other memory management details are not included, they are implementation-dependent and not a fundamental difference to C strings.

Pascal strings excel in... everything. NUL terminated strings save one to three bytes on short strings, which may have been useful in 1970 but isn't even worth mentioning today in virtually all circumstances. Aside from not being able to store a zero byte (which isn't too bad for text but rules out any kind of binary data), you can't determine string length efficiently. This affects a a good portion of string algorithms negatively. One example, in the comment you link to, is string comparison: If you have the length, you can instantly `return false` when comparing strings of different length. There are also many [other downsides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) not related to performance.

For these reasons, virtually every language implementation newer than about 1980 uses length prefixes for strings. This is another reason why the "pascal string" name is outdated.

Comment: actually in the "old days" - null terminated string is not saving anything over a shortstring (back then "String"):
[0]=3,[1]=O,[2]=z,[3]=z    (that uses 4 bytes - Pascal String)
[0]=O,[1]=z,[2]=z,[3]=0    (that uses 4 bytes - C String)

Comment: In the C case. In the Modula2 (Pascal's successor) form of zero terminated strings there is no terminating zero if the string fills the allocation size completely. This takes advantage of the fact that most heap management systems have that allocation size anyway.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: The same is true of many C-langugage string handling routines which, if passed a buffer size, will operate on the whole buffer if there's no zero byte within it, or else operate on the portion up to the zero.  Using that kind of data structure saves a byte versus even a maximally compact length prefix.

Comment: @supercat: I assume the -n- functions of C99 are closer to the Modula 2 system.  The older routines don't have any buffer length info.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: The strnlen (useful for working with zero-padded strings) and strncpy routines (convert from zero-terminated to zero-padded) existed in C89, as did the length specifier option for `%s` in `printf`-family functions.  Aside from the `strncat` which has almost no reasonable use cases, I don't think C99 added more functions for use with zero-padded strings.  The "safe" functions that were added after C89 treat a failure to find a zero byte within an expected length as an error, rather than an expected condition.