# What is a Pascal-style string?

Tags: string, encoding, pascal

The [Photoshop file format documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/) mentions *Pascal strings* without explaining what they are.

So, what are they, and how are they encoded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Pascal-style string has one leading byte (`length`), followed by `length` bytes of character data.

This means that Pascal-style strings can only encode strings of between 0 and 255 characters in length (assuming single-byte character encodings such as ASCII).

As an aside, another popular string encoding is *C-style strings* which have no length specifier, but use a zero-byte to denote the end of the string. They therefore have no length limit.

Yet other encodings may use a greater number of prefix bytes to facilitate longer strings. Terminator bytes/sentinels may also be used along with length prefixes.

Comment: This description is correct, but it applies to traditional Pascal strings only. Modern Object Pascal dialects like those in Delphi, Free Pascal and Lazarus support a plethora of string types with different encodings and some of them without length limit. See http://wiki.freepascal.org/Character_and_string_types for reference. I assume, however that "Pascal strings" in the Photoshop documentation refers to traditional Pascal strings.

Comment: Indeed, the (rather long-lived) Photoshop spec uses _Pascal string_ in place of the more precise [_Pascal ShortString_](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Character_and_string_types#ShortString). Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Only Delphi renamed "string" to shortstring because they introduced ansistring. The origin of string afaik is UCSD Pascal, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068903/what-are-pascal-strings/25079998#25079998