# Difference between c++ and pascal strings

Tags: c++, string, pascal, allocation

Am curious to know what the difference is with string allocation in c++ compared to pascal.

How do the strings get allocated?

C++ also has char arrays/char*/const char*, how do these all differ in their allocation and use?

Comment: You can figure out the C++ side from somewhere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/3484570).

Comment: This question has very well defined narrow answers. It's not broad at all, not to mention "too broad".

Comment: I've voted to reopen because I'm sure I'll learn something from this question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf _"Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once."_

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton _avoid_ does not mean _do not_. If this question is unperfect, you can [edit] it to improve it.

Comment: @YSC No, it means _"keep away from or stop oneself from doing (something)."_, meaning you _shouldn't do it_, otherwise the question is likely to be closed. The question can still be edited regardless of it being on hold or not, once the question is edited to be more on-topic, it will be taken off hold.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Answering this question would mean you write an article on how C-strings work and how Pascal strings work and the differences between them. There is no bound to such an answer and you can never be done. The question therefore fits the "too broad" close-reason very well.

Comment: Delphi strings are copy on write (COW) with length and ref count as preamble. They could be zero based or 1 based to add to the confusion.

Comment: @LURD: Delphi strings are not necessarily Pascal strings. Visit WIkipedia to learn what the latter means.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, exactly. That is why I stated Delphi strings.

Comment: @nwp For what it's worth I agree with you. This is apples and oranges.

Comment: Wow so much dispute over what was a question intended to further my knowledge

Comment: Also while there are multiple distinct questions, they are both linked quite closely. 1) difference between c++ and pascal string allocation 2) how are strings actually allocated. Both questions can be answered together without that much effort. I'm not asking for an essay or a 100,000 word report. Merely a basic summary. If none can be given than i really don't think any derogatory comments are required

Comment: @Cheers: I do understand and know both kinds of strings very well and that is why I know this question is too broad and off-topic here. I vote to close it. Note that Pascal strings are handled differently in different Pascal implementations, and that e.g. Delphi and FreePascal have several different string implementations (ShortString, AnsiString, UnicodeString, WideString) which are allocated and used differently, so this is an extremely broad topic. But also C++ has several string types: the char* type, the std::string and std::basic_string types, etc.etc. Far too broad.

Comment: @JackMcCall: no, they can not be answered without much effort. The topic is much broader than you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string that consists of a length followed by a sequence of character codes is called a [**Pascal string**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Length-prefixed). It's more descriptively called a length-prefixed string. For example, a string created with the Windows API's `SysAllocString` function, is a length-prefixed string, a.k.a. Pascal string.

A C++ raw string literal instead consists of character codes followed by a nullvalue, a **zero terminated string**.

As of C++11 and later C++ `std::string` has a buffer that can be viewed as a zero-terminated string, but it also has a separate explicit length. It's not specified where either the length or the buffer is stored. This varies between implementations.

---

Storage for a zero-terminated string or Pascal string can be allocated in any way you wish, dynamically or as a local variable.

With a C++ `std::string` the buffer must *in general* be dynamically allocated, via the the standard allocator that `std::string` is equipped with, because the string can be abritrarily large, and because there is no way for client code to supply a buffer.

However, unlike a `std::vector` there are no requirements on `std::string` that prohibit a fixed size buffer for small enough strings, and so many (most?) implementations now provide the *short string optimization*. For a short enough string value everything can then be fit directly within the `std::string` object. E.g. as a local variable.

---

There is a C++11 and later constant time requirement on `operator[]` for `std::string`, which effectively prevents the COW (Copy On Write) shared ownership strategy used by some C++03 implementations.

Comment: That is a horrible wiki paragraph, and entirely unsourced. Obviously the author never knew much about pascal strings.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: I agree with what you literally write. The author of the Wikipedia para seems to limit the concept to an octet-sized length prefix, as in Turbo Pascal, so I included the Windows `SysAllocString` example as a little counter-weight. There is not bad SO answer about Pascal strings (the general concept, not the literal "strings used in Pascal implementations") (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068903/what-are-pascal-strings).

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: That said, I learned Pascal in 1982, on the HP3000, when with most implementations we used `packed array of char` as strings. However, the second year at college we got to use a DEC Rainbow little workstation with UCSD p-Pascal. As I recall with a `string` type... :-)

Comment: If you mean the first reply there, I agree for obvious reasons. It is also why the link "UCSD Pascal" in my post links to the article that you named. Btw, what was the way of ending in your Hp3000 pascal? Space padding ?

Comment: Oh, that's you. Sorry, I didn't notice. Need coffee!

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: It must have been, because I don't remember any use of zero-termination or like that. We used mainly two Pascal versions on the HP3000, one that I think was from HP, and the other from Robelle Consulting in Canada. I think. It's long ago.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple implementations of Pascal strings. The Turbo Pascal string is mostly statically allocated, and the string types that are new in Delphi are dynamic. Delphi strings have a null at the end (but are not null-terminated, the strings can contain null characters), and Turbo Pascal are not. Delphi has 4 or 5 such types, including the Turbo Pascal one.

However both adhere to the same rough template that [UCSD Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068903/what-are-pascal-strings/25079998#25079998) (of bytecode interpreter fame) coined.

In a lot of C-centric literature "Pascal Strings" is usually about one of the key characteristics, storing the length of a string so that retrieving the length or a pointer to the last character is an O(1) operation.

In addition, Delphi/Free Pascal also can fully emulate manual C strings, since that is basically a library construct apart from literal assignment.

Comment: Thanks :) that's given me a good starting point

Comment: You might want to read this article: ["PChars: no strings attached"](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pchars.html) too. It is about Delphi's string types and how they relate to C-style "strings", but should be useful for all kinds of Pascal implementation.